# Chain jQuery ajax function and normal function in jQuery .net

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a function YR.printGraphs(). This does a number of ajax calls and plots the graphs.

I have to execute some script after completion of all ajax calls but I am unable to do that. I tried the below, also deferred way noting seems working for me.

The function "sangeetha" never fires. What am I doing wrong?

```
$("#pnlEmail1").ready(function () {
    YR.printGraphs();
}).sangeetha();

function sangeetha() {
    var s = 0.0;
    $(".printgraphs").each(function () {
        s += parseFloat($(this).height());
    });

    s = s - parseFloat($("#pnlEmail1").height());

    $(".fulldtls").css({ "top": s + "px", "position": "relative" });
}

printGraphs: function () {
        ///<summary>Loop through the email metrics available for this customer and makes ajax calls to get the email graph data.</summary>
        $(".printgraphs").each(function () {

            //Every div id is generated with its respective tab name in printreport.cs to distingush graphs.
            // So, check if the div belongs to Email tab, Phone tab or Grades and send the respective tab name to controller to get the correct graph data.
            if ($(this).attr("id").toLowerCase().indexOf("email") >= 0) {
                YAHOO.Report.changeGraph("Email", $(this), true);
            }
            else if ($(this).attr("id").toLowerCase().indexOf("grade") >= 0) {
                YAHOO.Report.changeGraph("Grades", $(this), true);
            }
            else {
                YAHOO.Report.changeGraph("Phone", $(this), true);
            }
        });
     }
```

Every YAHOO.Report.changeGraph makes an ajax call. I heard of function chaining in jQuery but not sure how to apply it in this scenario.

Comment: ready handler is supposed to be bind to document only, even using your syntax, this will works but maybe not as you expect, fired at DOM ready not when your element is 'ready' (which anyway doesn't make much sense). You are using method sangeetha() on the jquery object which doesn't have such method. `sangeetha()` is a fuction (global scope?), to call  it, use: `sangeetha();`

Comment: if I call sangeetha() directly, i am not getting the height of all graphs. I get that only after completion of all ajax calls.not sure how to invoke sangeetha() function.

Comment: You can't chain regular functions, only functions declared with `$.fn.functionName = function() {...` can be chained like that. You have to execute the function the regular way once the ajax calls have completed, but without knowing what `YAHOO.Report` returns, it's hard to say how exactly to do that.

Comment: Ya, as @adeneo said, could you check what returns `YAHOO.Report.changeGraph()`? I mean: `console.log(YAHOO.Report.changeGraph());`

Comment: it doesnot return anything, this has ajax success functions which plots the graphs

Comment: @mmssaann doesn't it expose a promise interface?

Comment: nope, sorry i have no idea what is promise?

Comment: So when you do: `console.log(YAHOO.Report.changeGraph(...));` there is nothing in console?

Comment: in page i will get the graph. the graph is build from the results returned from mvc action through ajax jquery. in the success method we just assign graph data to the divid.